# Regular Expression for Jira Issue Key

Tags: regex, jira

I need to get Jira issue key from message. 

Message may be like:

 - Merge branch "feature/author/fix_some_critical_issues" into trunk. https://jira.com/jira/browse/MYPROJ-00001. The date data binding creating has been fixed.

 - Some attribute has been added for legal entity in the products.
Task: https://jira.com/jira/browse/MYPROJ-00002

 - implemented: some feature was implemented (https://jira.com/jira/browse/MYPROJ-00003)


Help me create a pattern which get to me only "MYPROJ-NNNNN" from these messages.

Comment: Something like this `MYPROJ-\d+` (if the Ns are fixed then try `MYPROJ-\d{5}`) should work for you but I highly recommend you to have a look into [`regex`](https://regexone.com/lesson/introduction_abcs) yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admin, System, Advanced shows the local Jira instance's project key pattern, by default ([A-Z][A-Z0-9]+)
Then it's digits